# What are all the automorphisms of a group of order $9$ generated by two elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be a group of order $9$ generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ such that $a^3 = b^3 =e$.

How to determine all possible automorphisms of $G$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the result that a group of order $p^2$, $p$ a prime, is always abelian? This will lead up to the first step in Martin's answer. Just making sure that you won't get stuck at the starting gate. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

1. Show $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.
2. Regard this as a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_3$.
3. Apply what you know from linear algebra.

Comment: Martin Brandenburg, this will be the case only if $G$ be abelian. Can we conclude that $G$ is necessarily abelian?

Comment: Yes, groups of order $p^2$ are abelian. Probably the fastest proof uses the well-known exercise that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian, as well as the fact that a non-trivial $p$-group has a non-trivial center.